# Getting the cursor position in an input field using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this text on an input element: `BT25 3___ ____ ____ ____`.

I need to know the index of the character where I clicked with the mouse. More specific I need to find what is the index of the clicked value?

It need to be functional in IE11.

Comment: in IE, isn't there an `input.selectionStart` or `input.selStart`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `selectionEnd` on `mouseup` event:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
  console.log("pos:", this.selectionEnd);
});
```

```html
<input value="BT25 3___ ____ ____ ____">
```

There's no compatibility problem, it even works on IE9.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question, I saw that the selectionEnd and selectionStart works with the "onclick" and 'mouseup' events. Is it possible to make it work and on a keyboard event?

Comment: @ttdol2506 You don't even need an event, input.selectionStart and input.selectionEnd are always available on the input.